# Bracket Combinations

Tags: c#

Have the function BracketCombinations(num) read num which will be an integer greater than or equal to zero, and return the number of valid combinations that can be formed with num pairs of parentheses. For example, if the input is 3, then the possible combinations of 3 pairs of parenthesis, namely: ()()(), are ()()(), ()(()), (())(), ((())), and (()()). There are 5 total combinations when the input is 3, so your program should return 5.

```
public static int BracketCombinations(int num) 
{

    // code goes here  
    return num;
    

  }

  static void Main() {  
    // keep this function call here
    Console.WriteLine(BracketCombinations(Console.ReadLine()));
  }
```

Examples

Input: 3
Output: 5

Input: 2
Output: 2

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) ([OEIS A000108](https://oeis.org/A000108)). The only problem is that these numbers *grow fast* (~ `4**n`), that's why
you should be careful with *integer overflow*:

```
    public static int BracketCombinations(int num) {
      if (num < 0 || num > 19)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(num));

      long result = 1;

      for (int k = 1; k < num; ++k)
        result = 2 * (2 * k + 1) * result / (k + 2);

      return (int)result;
    }
```

**Demo:**

```
    var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
      .Range(0, 20)
      .Select(x => $"{x,2} => {BracketCombinations(x)}"));

    Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 0 => 1
 1 => 1
 2 => 2
 3 => 5
 4 => 14
 5 => 42
 6 => 132
 7 => 429
 8 => 1430
 9 => 4862
10 => 16796
11 => 58786
12 => 208012
13 => 742900
14 => 2674440
15 => 9694845
16 => 35357670
17 => 129644790
18 => 477638700
19 => 1767263190
```

Comment: It's not fully application of Catalan number if we consider the validity of the parenthesis. 
Total possible valid expressions for input n is n/2’th Catalan Number if n is even and 0 if n is odd.

Edit :
source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-valid-parentheses-expressions-given-length/